# Certificate errors browser / network

Tags: certificate

I have a problem where I browse to my website using wireless network on my mobile phone using Chrome and I get a certificate error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. If I browse to the same website using 4G connection I do not get the error. 
Any suggestions how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you browse with some other device, i.e. laptop or something, does the same error persist? Also do you use the same address to browse from 4G as from WiFi?

Comment: No, I do not get the error using a laptop or another device. Just seems to be using my phone using the wireless connection. Yes, I use the same address  to browse from 4G as from WiFi.It seems to be only using the wireless network